# How to look for entries only in first column in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have three columns A,B,C. All have email ids, now i want to match emails ids in column A with column B and column C and after that list unique email ids which are only in column A but not the duplicate ones.
Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are not a code-writing service, but we are happy to assist you on your path to learning. Please show us the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood the questions right, but from my understanding, this might work.
Let me know if it's not what you want

```
Sub LIST_UNIQUE_EMAILS()
    RECORD_COUNT = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each EMAIL In Range("A1:A" & RECORD_COUNT).Value
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns("B:C"), EMAIL) = 0 Then
            i = i + 1
            Range("D" & i) = EMAIL
        End If
    Next EMAIL
End Sub
```

Above code will write Unique emails to column "D"